# How to read the result of method: listSubscriptions from Youtube PHP API

Tags: php, youtube-api

After this method I've gotten this format of object bellow. Can anyone help me how to read the title and channelId from this object?

```
$subscriptionResponse = $youtube->subscriptions->listSubscriptions('snippet',
    array('channelId' => 'MY_CHANEL_ID', 'maxResults' => '50'));

echo "<pre>";
         print_r($subscriptionResponse['items']);
echo "</pre>";
                  die();    

Array
(
    [0] => Google_Service_YouTube_Subscription Object
        (
            [contentDetailsType:protected] => Google_Service_YouTube_SubscriptionContentDetails
            [contentDetailsDataType:protected] =>
            [etag] => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            [id] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            [kind] => youtube#subscription
            [snippetType:protected] => Google_Service_YouTube_SubscriptionSnippet
            [snippetDataType:protected] =>
            [subscriberSnippetType:protected] => Google_Service_YouTube_SubscriptionSubscriberSnippet
            [subscriberSnippetDataType:protected] =>
            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [snippet] => Array
                        (
                            [publishedAt] => 2014-03-04T13:51:59.000Z
                            [title] => THIS IS THE CHANNEL TITLE THAT I WANT TO GET
                            [description] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                            [resourceId] => Array
                                (
                                    [kind] => youtube#channel
                                    [channelId] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                                )

                            [channelId] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                            [thumbnails] => Array
                                (
                                    [default] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/-b1X29Q2BT6A/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/QdK_MNBrNRU/s88-c-k-no/photo.jpg
                                        )

                                    [high] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/-b1X29Q2BT6A/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/QdK_MNBrNRU/s240-c-k-no/photo.jpg
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [processed:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Google_Service_YouTube_Subscription Object
        (
            [contentDetailsType:protected] => Google_Service_YouTube_SubscriptionContentDetails
            [contentDetailsDataType:protected] =>
            [etag] => "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            [id] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            [kind] => youtube#subscription
            [snippetType:protected] => Google_Service_YouTube_SubscriptionSnippet
            [snippetDataType:protected] =>
            [subscriberSnippetType:protected] => Google_Service_YouTube_SubscriptionSubscriberSnippet
            [subscriberSnippetDataType:protected] =>
            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [snippet] => Array
                        (
                            [publishedAt] => 2014-03-04T13:50:42.000Z
                            [title] => THIS IS THE CHANNEL TITLE THAT I WANT TO GET 
                            [description] =>
                            [resourceId] => Array
                                (
                                    [kind] => youtube#channel
                                    [channelId] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                                )

                            [channelId] => xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
                            [thumbnails] => Array
                                (
                                    [default] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/-PYEumYpZ18E/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/LIZhzGw24w4/s88-c-k-no/photo.jpg
                                        )

                                    [high] => Array
                                        (
                                            [url] => https://yt3.ggpht.com/-PYEumYpZ18E/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/LIZhzGw24w4/s240-c-k-no/photo.jpg
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [processed:protected] => Array
                (
                )

        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work?

```
foreach ($subscriptionResponse['items'] as $item) {
 echo $item['data']['snippet']['title']; 
 echo $item['data']['snippet']['channelId'];
}
```